# 500 Internal Server Error Flask Api on Lighttpd

Tags: flask, raspberry-pi, fastcgi, lighttpd

I've struggling for few days to build Flask Api under Lighttpd (under Rasp Pi) but having problem of "500 Internal Server Error".

under "**/var/www/api/api.py**",

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def home():

    #return "<h3>TestLine</h3>"
    return jsonify("TestLine")

@app.route("/GetDevice", methods=["GET"])
def getdevice():

    Subject = request.args.get("Subject")

    return jsonify("TestLine 123")

app.run(host = "0.0.0.0", port = 80)
```

under "**/var/www/api/api.fcgi**",

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer
from api import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    WSGIServer(app, debug = True).run()
```

under "**/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf**",

```
debug.log-request-handling = "enable"

server.modules   += ( "mod_fastcgi" )

server.modules   += ( "mod_rewrite" )

server.modules   += ( "mod_alias" )

server.modules   += ( "mod_accesslog" )

server.document-root        = "/var/www"

#server.port = 80

server.modules += ( "mod_cgi" )

mimetype.assign = (
 ".html" => "text/html", 
 ".txt" => "text/plain",
 ".jpg" => "image/jpeg",
 ".png" => "image/png",
 ".js" => "text/javascript",
 ".css" => "text/css"
)

static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".fcgi", ".php", ".rb", ".inc", ".pl" )

cgi.assign                 = ( ".pl"  => "/usr/bin/perl",
                       ".cgi" => "/usr/bin/perl",
                       ".rb"  => "/usr/bin/ruby",
                       ".erb" => "/usr/bin/eruby",
                       ".py"  => "/usr/bin/python",
                       ".php" => "/usr/bin/php-cgi" )

index-file.names   += ( "index.pl",   "default.pl",
                       "index.rb",   "default.rb",
                       "index.erb",  "default.erb",
                       "index.py",   "default.py",
                       "index.php",  "default.php" )

server.errorlog    = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
accesslog.filename = "/var/log/lighttpd/access.log"

fastcgi.debug = 1
fastcgi.server = ("/api.fcgi" =>
  ((
     "socket" => "/tmp/api-fcgi.sock",
     "bin-path" => "/var/www/api/api.fcgi",
     "check-local" => "disable",
     "max-procs" => 1
  ))
)

alias.url = ( 
   "/api/" => "/var/www/api"
)

url.rewrite-once = (
  "^(/api($|/.*))$" => "$1",
  "^(/.*)$" => "/api.fcgi$1"
)
```

There is no error when running "/var/www/api/api.fcgi" under terminal.
I hoped someone could sincerely help me to point the mistake and appreciate to thank.

Answer (score 0):

lighttpd runs on port 80 in your config.  When lighttpd tries to start the backend, the backend will fail because your python code is also trying to listen on port 80

```
app.run(host = "0.0.0.0", port = 80)
```

Since you have configured lighttpd to start the backend, you should config it to listen on stdin.  lighttpd creates the socket you have configured ("/tmp/api-fcgi.sock") and starts up the backend with that socket on stdin of your app.